Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden: [403] {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match signature you provided
require "faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4"

class AmazonElasticSearchClient
  def self.client
    return Elasticsearch::Client.new(url: ENV["AWS_ELASTICSEARCH_URL"]) do |f|
      f.request :aws_signers_v4,
                service_name: 'es',
                credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]),
                region: ENV["AWS_REGION"],
                timeout: 20,
                logs: true,
                open_timeout: 10
    end
  end
end
if ENV["AWS_ELASTICSEARCH_URL"].present?
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = AmazonElasticSearchClient.client
else
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9200', logs: true})
end


I am using faraday to create aws signature key, its working fine most of time, but sometimes i am seeing this error
It seems there is some query string issue, may be with white spaces etc,
It may have issue with managing date, or clock syncing
